# Send an array of objects with photos to php through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, photo

```
$("#CreateReportObject").click(function () {
  var report_array = [];
  var object_id;

  $("#report-container [id^='report-']").each(function (index) {

    var reportObject = {
      subject: $("#name-report-" + index).text(),
      photo: $("input[name='subject-photo-" + index + "']")[0].files[0],
      rating: $("input[name='subject-rating-" + index + "']").val(),
      comment: $("textarea[name='subject-comment-" + index + "']").val(),
    };
    report_array.push(reportObject);
    object_id = $("input[name='object_id-" + index + "']").val();
  });
  console.log(report_array);
```

Hello! I collect an array of objects in my `report_array`. It gives me this in console:
[image]

How to send it to php through [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)?

Please note that i need to get also all photos in php. How can i do this?

Comment: check with this -> `print_r(json_decode($_POST[]));` you can get all the data passed through ajax.

Comment: I use :
`$object = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['params']));
print_r($object);`

And i get: 
`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [subject] => Окна
            [photo] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [rating] => 0
            [comment] => comment1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [subject] => Пол
            [photo] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [rating] => 0
            [comment] => comment2
        )

)`

Comment: comment that and do print this `print_r(json_decode($_POST[]));` it gives all the values that passed through ajax

Comment: and below that do `print_r('$_FILES[]');`. if you are uploading any file.

Comment: empty result gives me

Comment: which one Files array or Post ?

Comment: Sorry, but can we connect somehow? Maybe skype? if you have time... It will be easier

Comment: i dont have have skype brother, sorry for that

Comment: if you getting data in post then there is no issue,

Comment: Hmm are you trying to upload an array `[{"subject":"Тестовый контент 1", "photo": File, "rating": "3", "comment": "Некоторые комментарии 1."}, {"subject":"Тестовый контент 2", "photo": File, "rating": "4", "comment": "Некоторые комментарии 2."}]` where `File` is a file that you have selected, all this through AJAX?